# Android Screen On And Off Make Which Method is called

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Which **Method** is called when Android screen is became **off** and **on**.
When Android screen is became off **onPause and etc** and when Andriod screen is became on **onResume and etc** is called I want to know isn't any special method just for screen on and off purpose in **Activity** or particular in ***Fragment***.

Answer (score 2):

As screen turns off your activity becomes invisible which triggers **onPause** followed by **onStop**

Screen on, on the other hand, triggers **onStart** followed by **onResume**.

Having said that, you best way for detecting screen events will be to register a broadcast receiver for

```
"android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_ON"
"android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF"
```

See code example [here](http://zeering.com/LoadAnswers.aspx?q=Android%20-%20how%20to%20receive%20broadcast%20intents%20ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF?).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about your activity getting visible/invisible check [`onResume`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) and [`onPause`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) of the [activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) in the Android documentation.

If you are talking about screen on and off, check [`BroadcastReceivers`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for the `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON` and `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` events.

Have a look at [this example](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

screen off  **onPause > onStop** (1st onPause get called then onStop)

screen on-> **onStart > onResume** (1st onStart get called then onResume)

please see activityLifecycle diagram

[Diagram of activity life cycle](http://blog.cloverink.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/activity_lifecycle.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want is this, but this will able to turn the screen on and off.

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

// Choice 1
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);

// Choice 2
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

Also you will need this premission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

If want you want to know what method is called when the App becomes active again is the

**onResume()**

You should @Override it if you want to make any changes.